# Unhide items by clicking at Commandbutton

Tags: vba, excel

Using excel 2010. I have a workbook with several worksheets. In one sheet (called: "main") I have protected things like: menubar, formulabar, statusbar, gridlines etc etc. I have a password protected Commandbutton which should unhide the "hidden things". However when I click at that Commandbutton and enter the right password, there will be nothing unhide. In VBA I have for the appr. sheet:

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
    Dim pw As String
    Dim a As CommandBar
    pw = InputBox("Give password")
    If pw <> "mypassword" Then
        MsgBox "Wrong password"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = False
            .DisplayFullScreen = True
            With .CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar")
                .Enabled = True
                .Visible = True
            End With
            .CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = True
            .CommandBars("Standard").Visible = True
            .CommandBars("Formatting").Visible = True
            .DisplayFormulaBar = True
            .DisplayStatusBar = True
        End With
        With ActiveWindow
                .DisplayHeadings = True
                .DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
                .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True
                .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = True
                .DisplayGridlines = True
        End With
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

So my question is, why is this not working or how can I - without closing the workbook - unhide the hidden items.

Comment: I'm not clear on how you expect those Excel 2003 menus - Worksheet Menu Bar, Standard and Formatting to become visible in Excel 2010. Could you clarify which parts aren't working and what you expect to happen?

Comment: Dough, when I open the workbook for the 1st time the Menu Bar, Formulabar etc. are hidden because I let them hide by the sub Workbook_Open of ThisWorkbook in VBE. So normally you do not see a menubar formulabar etc. Sometimes I want to see the menubar, formulabar and thus I created a Commandbutton which - when clicked - should show me the menubar formulabar etc again and therefor in the code above all those items are set to True. But when I now click at that Commandbutton everything stays hidden unfortunately.

Comment: Again, three of those items - the ones I listed above - are Excel 2003 menus, so they won't be visible in Excel 2010. If you step through your code with F8, do you actually get to the lines that would set the properties back to true, i.e., is your password really "mypassword?"

Comment: When I step with F8 there is no error and it steps through all lines, but as far as I can see nothing changed in Excel at my screen. The password I changed of course and that part is working fine. BTW if 3 items are for Excel 2003 only what should I use in 2010?